# How to make my sensor reads when i pressed the button

Tags: button, loop

Hi I'm making a digital fare meter, I have a problem in how my sensor reads when I'd pressed the button(single tap). I need the sensor to read once I pressed the button because when I press the button the reading starts from the beginning of the program(when the device starts) not when I pressed it. and the display is not changing if I not pressed the button i need the display in lcd to change even if i only press the button once. ( Sorry for my grammar )

```
#define sw 5 //pin at push sw is connected  
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>  
int irPin=A0;  
int count=0;  
int counter=0;  
boolean state = true;  
float distance1; float distance2; float distance3; float distance4;  
float wait1;float wait2;float wait3;float wait4;  
float fare1;float fare2;float fare3;float fare4;  
float hitObject = false;  

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd1(0x26,20,4);  
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4);  
int lastButtonState = HIGH;   // the previous reading from the input pin    
unsigned long lastDebounceTime = 0;  // the last time the output pin was toggled  
unsigned long debounceDelay = 50;    // the debounce time; increase if the output flickers  
bool buttonState = HIGH; //saving state of the switch  
byte tapCounter; //for saving no. of times the switch is pressed  
int timediff; //for saving the time in between each press and release of the switch  
bool flag1, flag2; //just two variables  
long double presstime, releasetime; //for saving millis at press and millis at release  
void setup() {  
 
lcd.init();  
lcd.backlight();  
lcd1.init();  
lcd1.backlight();  
pinMode(irPin, INPUT);  
lcd.setCursor(0,0); lcd.print("Seater 1  D=");  
  lcd.setCursor(0,1); lcd.print("Seater 2  D=0.00");  
  lcd.setCursor(0,2); lcd.print("Seater 3  D=0.00");  
  lcd.setCursor(0,3); lcd.print("Seater 4  D=0.00");  
  lcd1.setCursor(0,0); lcd1.print("W=       F=Php0.00");   
  lcd1.setCursor(0,1); lcd1.print("W=       F=Php0.00");   
  lcd1.setCursor(0,2); lcd1.print("W=       F=Php0.00");   
  lcd1.setCursor(0,3); lcd1.print("W=       F=Php0.00");   
  
  Serial.begin(9600); //for serial monitor  
  pinMode(sw, INPUT_PULLUP); //setting pin 5 as input with internal pull up resistor  
    
 

 
}  

void kount()  
    {  
  { if (!digitalRead(irPin) && state){  
 count++;  
 state = false;  
  
 }  
 if (digitalRead(irPin)){  
 state = true;}}}  
 void compute()  
   
{  
   distance1 = count*1.73;  
   fare1 = count*1.73/100+wait1;  
 }  
 void printlcd()  
   
 {  
 lcd.setCursor(12,0); lcd.println(distance1);lcd.println("m");  
  
 }  
  
 
 
void loop() {  
  kount();  
  compute();  
  int reading = digitalRead(sw);  
   
  if (reading != lastButtonState) {  
    // reset the debouncing timer  
    lastDebounceTime = millis();  
  }  
   
  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {  
    // whatever the reading is at, it's been there for longer than the debounce  
    // delay, so take it as the actual current state:  
   
    // if the button state has changed:  
    if (reading != buttonState) {  
      buttonState = reading;  
    }  
  }  
  //Serial.println(buttonState);  
   
  //when switch is pressed  
  if (buttonState == 0 && flag2 == 0)  
  {  
    presstime = millis(); //time from millis fn will save to presstime variable  
    flag1 = 0;  
    flag2 = 1;  
      
    tapCounter++; //tap counter will increase by 1  
    //delay(10); //for avoiding debouncing of the switch  
  }  
  //when sw is released  
  if (buttonState == 1 && flag1 == 0)  
  {  
    releasetime = millis(); //time from millis fn will be saved to releasetime var  
    flag1 = 1;  
    flag2 = 0;  
   
    timediff = releasetime - presstime; //here we find the time gap between press and release and stored  to timediff var  
    //Serial.println(timediff);  
    //delay(10);  
  }  
 
  if ((millis() - presstime) > 400 && buttonState == 1) //wait for some time and if sw is in release   position
  {  
    if (tapCounter == 1) //if tap counter is 1  
    {  
      if (timediff >= 400) //if time diff is larger than 400 then its a hold  
      {  
        Serial.println("Hold");  
        hold(); //fn to call when the button is hold  
        ;  
      }
      else //if timediff is less than 400 then its a single tap  
      {  
    
  

       
        Serial.print(count);  
        Serial.println("single tap");  
        singleTap();  
          
        //fn to call when the button is single taped  
      }  
    }  
    else if (tapCounter == 2 ) //if tapcounter is 2  
    {  
      if (timediff >= 400) // if timediff is greater than  400 then its single tap and hold  
      {  
        Serial.println("single tap and hold");  
        tapAndHold(); //fn to call when the button is single tap and hold  
      }  
      else // if timediff is less than 400 then its just double tap  
      {  
        Serial.println("double tap");  
        doubleTap(); //fn to call when doubletap  
      }  
    }  
    else if (tapCounter == 3) //if tapcounter is 3 //then its triple tap  
    {  
      Serial.println("triple tap");  
      tripleTap(); //fn to call when triple tap  
    }  
    else if (tapCounter == 4) //if tapcounter is 4 then its 4 tap  
    {  
      Serial.println("four tap");  
      fourTap();//fn to call when four tap  
    }  
    tapCounter = 0;  
  }  
  lastButtonState = reading;  
}  

void singleTap()  
{  
compute();  
printlcd();  
}  
void doubleTap()  
{  
  
}  
void tripleTap()  
{  
    
}  
void fourTap()  
{  
   
}  
void hold()  
{  
    
  
}  
void tapAndHold()  
{  
    
}
```